How to color the whole row in a Grafana table based on a value in a cell of that row
In Granafa, I have a Table visualization.
It has multiple columns say, City, Country and Volume.
How can I set the background /foreground of each row in the table if the value of Volume is below 1000?
I try using the Value Mapping, which set a rule with < 1000 and set color to Red, but no color is changed.

I don't think this is possible in the built in table, from like version 8. If you really need this, try looking into alternative table panels; I think I've seen something like that.

That's available from Grafana 11 https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/visualizations/panels-visualizations/visualizations/table/#color-background-gradient-or-solid

Oh cool! Hasn't got through release notes yet, but this is definitely a pleasant come back) @JanGaraj

In the v11 of Grafana, you can now color the all row based on a specific value of this one. You can see this video of the release explaining how to do that : https://youtu.be/PLfADTtCnmg
